# E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.kakao.sdk.auth.c$c

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flutter, kotlin

This error occurs when I download the app on your Samsung phone and try to log in after distributing it as an internal test on Google Play.

E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.kakao.sdk.auth.c$c
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kakao.sdk.auth.c$c

I don't know why I'm getting these errors. This is my MainApplication.java code, what code should I put here?

```
    package com.hey;

    import android.app.Application;
    import android.content.Context;
    import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

      private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
          new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
              return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
            }

            @Override
            protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
              @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
              List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
              // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
              return packages;
            }

            @Override
            protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
              return "index";
            }
          };

      @Override
      public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
      }

      /**
      * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
      * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
      *
      * @param context
      * @param reactInstanceManager
      */
      private static void initializeFlipper(
          Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
          try {
            /*
            We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
            since Flipper library is not available in release mode
            */
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.hey.ReactNativeFlipper");
            aClass
                .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
                .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`unmarshalling` error often caused by wrong handling parse a `Parcelable` object. Give a try [to search about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=unmarshalling%20android%20error%20site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ0dbqh_HxAhXJB94KHWHMAOYQrQIoBHoECAQQBQ&biw=1280&bih=608) , then look at the `Parcelable` class from the (nested of the) package `com.kakao.sdk.auth` to find the error.

Another hint, this may cause by enabling proguard. So, you can try to add the configurations for `Kakao SDK`. (Reference [the docs here](https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/en/getting-started/sdk-android#install))

```yaml
-keep class com.kakao.sdk.**.model.* { <fields>; }
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
```